# Exception: system.IO.FileNotFoundException: cannot find assembly or file Mysql.Data

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, runtime-error

When I execute my stand alone program it crashes and says:

```
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: cannot find assembly or file Mysql.Data  or load one of the dependable sources at project3.class.executesend<> at project3.class.initialize<> at project3.class.main<>
```

After some searching I found out that I should add those `.dll` files as resources with the program. After I did that, it produced the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't add the DLLs as *resources* - you just provide them alongside your application, in the same directory...

Comment: So i have to manualy send them along with the .exe they run ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Or build a setup project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added Mysql.Data in your project's references folder, if I understood well.

Now, right click on this in VS Explorer, go to properties, and set Attribute "Copy Local" to true.

So it will be copied in the "debug" or "release" folder whenever you build your app.

Comment: do i have to manualy include those with the .exe file or are they automaticly included along with it ?

Comment: if you set "Copy Local" to true, this will be done for you. Or you can let "Copy Local" to false and add them manually... Useless to say that first solution is easier.

Answer (score 0):

For version 8.0.19 of MySQL Workbench, I needed to install the Visual C++ 2015-2019 DLLs.

I had 2008, 2010, 2013 and 2015 installed, with both x64 and x32 flavors, and was getting this error.

Visual C++ Redistributables are here ...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads